# jQuery animate scrollTop not working with Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

The following code is only skipping to the top in Firefox, and only works as intended in Chrome. I've read here on StackOverflow, that for Firefox and IE you need `$('body,html')` in order to work, but it's still not. In chrome, it works perfectly. Any tips why it's not?

```
$('body,html').animate(
{ scrollTop: 0 }, // what we are animating )
{
    duration: 1000, // how fast we are animating
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo', // the type of easing
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `event.preventDefault();` from the code solved the issue.

Comment: This Solved my problem. Now working on firefox and chrome both. Thanks :)